# Query documents containing (or not) array of nested documents (being populated) but then matching a certain criteria

Tags: node.js, arrays, nested, document, populate

*Please read carefully (not just the title) before marking this as "already answered" (or something like that) because I really have researched for long time and did not find the solution yet (I found questions about querying nested array objects but not nested array documents which need to be populated).*

I'm working with latest versions of NodeJS and Mongoose.

For illustration, I'm gonna use these two models to help picturing my goal:

```
// Sections
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const sectionSchema = new Schema({
  _id:          Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:         { type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required.']},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Section', sectionSchema);
```

And:

```
// Departments
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const departmentSchema = new Schema({
  _id:          Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:         { type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required.']},
  sections:     [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Section' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Department', departmentSchema);
```

Consider I have these stored in the DB:

```
// Departments
_id: ObjectId("61b0f1971ad3890000000001")
name: "Department 1",
sections: [ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000b"), ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000c")]

_id: ObjectId("61b0f1971ad3890000000002")
name: "Department 2",
sections: [ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000a"), ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000c")]

_id: ObjectId("61b0f1971ad3890000000003")
name: "Department 3",
sections: []

_id: ObjectId("61b0f1971ad3890000000004")
name: "Department 4",
sections: [ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000b")]


// Sections
_id: ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000a")
name: "Section A"

_id: ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000b")
name: "Section B"

_id: ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000c")
name: "Section C"
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to fetch the departments containing no sections or sections with name "Section A" (a text coming as a filter from the frontend).

```
Department.find(criteria).select('name').populate('sections').then(results => {
    console.log('Departments: ', results.map(r => r.name));
});


// Should print:
Departments: [ Department 2, Department 3 ]
```

For the criteria, I've tried many different ways but none seems to work so far (I always get zero results). One example below:

```
const criteria = { 
  $or: [
    { 'sections': [] },
    { 'sections': { '$elemMatch': { name: 'Section A' }}},
  ]
};
```

I think this is because the `criteria` is tested before the query populates the array. If this is what is happening, what would be the best work around it? I wanted to avoid querying the two documents separately and then matching the results. **There should be a way to do this in one go**. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exhaustive testing and researching, I came to conclude there is no way to get the desired result **in one go** only by manipulating what fills the `criteria`.

The closest MongoDB documentation provided for [querying documents with nested/embedded array of other documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) does not deal with `populate`.

Therefore, the current/next best way to achieve the goal (of printing the departments containing no sections or 'Section A' while having no provided section._id but the section.name only) is:

```
Section.find({ name: 'Section A' }).then(sections => {
  Department.find({ 
    $or: [
      { 'sections': [] },
      { 'sections': { $in: sections }},
    ]
  }).then(departments => console.log('Departments: ', results.map(r => r.name));
  // Will print: Departments: [ Department 2, Department 3 ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let s look at your query.
You want to find documents with section [] or section name to be 'Section A'. but in your Department model, you just saved **id** of each section. you can not access to name filed before populating.so you need to find documents based on section id.
you can change the criteria like below.

```
    const criteria = {
    $or: [
        { 'sections': [] },
        { 'sections': mongoose.Types.ObjectId("61b26a3fb756a1000000000a") }
    ]
};
```

it s clear that you can not access the name filed before populating. you can also filter on populate but I did not find a solution to cover both conditions. you can also read [populate  documentations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions).

one way is to fetch all documents and populate them and then implement a filter but I think it's not a good approach.

```
//Fetch and populate all documents
const departments = await Department.find({
}).populate({
    path: 'sections',
    select: 'name',
}).exec();

let res = [];
departments.forEach(department => {
    //Select departments which has "Section A" or has not any section
    if (department.sections.some(section => section.name === "Section A") || department.sections.length === 0) {
        res.push(department);
    }
});
```

Comment: The thing is that it should be able to find all departments containing no sections or only the ones provided by its name. Of course I could do it in two steps: `Section.find({ name: 'Section A").then(foundSection => { Department.find(criteria including foundSection.id) });` but then I wouldn't be doing it in one go.

Comment: When we do a Department.find().populate('sections') we get each department containing its section populated with section._id and section.name in the returning data. Well then I would like to filter what is going to be returned by placing somehow the section name inside the criteria for Department.find(). From what I've found so far, '$elemMatch' would be the best way to do it because is built for querying objects inside nested arrays, but it is not working in my case. Maybe someone knows another way... perhaps combining with something else (?)

Comment: As i said you can query with section id insted of section name (which you can not access before populating). Do you see and test my suggested ciriteria? It will return the correct result.

Comment: I understand it will work if we query with section id. But this is not what I am asking. I am trying to explain the query will be called from the frontend (by the client) with the section name only (no section id will be provided).